# Can I use these forms to ask about the needed time?

Tags: questions

I've watched [this video](http://www.engvid.com/learn-english-grammar-how-long-does-it-take/).

But I used other forms for asking about the needed time for doing something, and I want to know if I can use these forms or not, like:

> 1. How much time did you need to finish your homework?
> 2. How long will you need to go home?
> 3. How much time does the technical office need to fix my problem?
> 4. How long does the technical office need to fix my problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unproductive. The video gives advice on using *how long . . .* and it's not reasonable to therefore assume that other ways of asking about time are invalid. The OP merely asks if a list of questions can be used. It's unlikely to produce generally useful answers, and is overly broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred forms in the UK are "how long will it take?" and "how much time will you need?" The difference in the meaning is quite small, and there may be regional or cultural variations (eg between the US and the UK) in which is preferred. (Jim Reynolds might be correct in implying that the difference is not very important.)

As a native English speaker in the UK my preferences are :

1. This is ok. Equally good is "How long did it take you to finish your homework?"
2. Better would be "How much time will you need for the journey home?" or "How long will it take you to get home?"
3. This is already good, but better is "How much time *will* the technical office need to fix my problem?"
4. This should be either "How long will it take the technical office to fix my problem?" or the same as 3 above.